# Insert a element in String array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have string containing n elements.

I want to insert a automatically incremented number to the first position.

E.g
    Data

```
66,45,34,23,39,83
64,46,332,73,39,33 
54,76,32,23,96,42
```

I am  spliting to string to array with split char ','

I want resultant array with a incremented number a first position

```
1,66,45,34,23,39,83
2,64,46,332,73,39,33
3,54,76,32,23,96,42
```

Please suggest how can I do it.

Thanks

Comment: In what way is that a string array? It looks more like an `int[][]` to me.

Comment: When you say 'Please suggest how can i do it.', are you sure you dont mean, 'Do it for me.'

Comment: Given that arrays are accessed by index, you can assume that the element at index `i` has an implicit `i+1` as the first member of the list.

Comment: @Ash - some questions are just like that.  It doesn't make them any less valid.  "Please suggest how can I do it" is about as good as it gets

Comment: Yes it is a little surprising but you can do Array.insert
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383995.aspx

Answer (score 19):

You can't with an array, you need to use a `List<string>` instead.

For example:

```
List<string> words = new string[] { "Hello", "world" }.ToList();
words.Insert(0, "Well");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a little cleaner to use:  List<string> words = new List<string> {"Hello", "World"};  ?

Answer (score 16):

Linq has an easy way to accomplish your "mission":

First add the correct namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And then:

```
// Translate your splitted string (array) in a list:
var myList = myString.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList<string>();

// Where insertPosition is the position you want to insert in:
myList.Insert(insertingPosition, insertedString);

// Back to array:
string[] myArray = myList.ToArray<string>();
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 5):

You cannot insert anything to Array. Use `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use something like an [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) instead, which has an [ArrayList.Insert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.insert.aspx) method.

```
   ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
   myAL.Insert( 0, "The" );
   myAL.Insert( 1, "fox" );
   myAL.Insert( 2, "jumps" );
   myAL.Insert( 3, "over" );
   myAL.Insert( 4, "the" );
   myAL.Insert( 5, "dog" );
```

Answer (score 3):

well what if you have the list like the following

```
string a="66,45,34,23,39,83";
string b="64,46,332,73,39,33"; 
string c="54,76,32,23,96,42";
```

before splitting a,b,c...

```
string[] s=new string[]{a,b,c};

for(int i=0; i<s.length;i++){
    s[i]=(i+1)+s[i];
}
```

now split each string in s

you will have a list like

1,66,45,34,23,39,83 
2,64,46,332,73,39,33 
3,54,76,32,23,96,42

I am not sure if I have understood your problem or not. :|

Answer (score 1):

I know you want a C# answer (and there are good answers here already in that language), but I'm learning F# and took this on in that language as a learning exercise.

So, assuming you want an array of strings back and are willing to use F#...

```
let aStructuredStringArray = [|"66,45,34,23,39,83"
                               "64,46,332,73,39,33"
                               "54,76,32,23,96,42"|]

let insertRowCountAsString (structuredStringArray: string array) =
    [| for i in [0 .. structuredStringArray.Length-1] 
        do yield String.concat "" [ i.ToString(); ","; structuredStringArray.[i]]
            |]

printfn "insertRowCountAsString=%A" (insertRowCountAsString aStructuredStringArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

C# arrays cannot be resized. This means that you can't insert items.

You have two options:

1. Use a `List<T>` instead.
2. Create a new array, with one extra item in, copy the contents of the old one across and so on.

Option 1 is invariably to be preferred.

---

There is [`Array.Resize(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx). On the face of it this contradicts what I state above. However, the documentation for this method states:

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one.