# How can I start a splitted string from index 1 instead of 0?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have the following code, which reads a line from the console:

```
// Read text from input
var inputText = Console.ReadLine();
var inputTextSplit = inputText.Split(' ');
```

A possible input might be: Hello my name is John. If I try to iterate over this input now, "Hello" will be the first index (0). So inputTextSplit[0] will be equal to Hello, inputTextSplit[1] will be equal to "my", etc. What I'm trying to achieve is a way to make the index counting start at 1. So I want inputTextSplit[0] to have no value (or any filler value), and inputTextSplit[1] be "Hello", inputTextSplit[2] be "my", etc.

Comment: Odd requirement.  But could be as simple as ("ignore " + inputText).Split(' ')

Comment: Very weird requirement. Could you explain why you need to have the first index empty? This looks like a lot as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Arrays start from zero because it's faster. Take the memory address of the start of the array, add the index and that's where the object is stored. The first item is stored in the same place as the start of the array, so the offset is zero.

Comment: why do you want indexing from 1?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, here are a few

**Given**

```
var inputText = Console.ReadLine();
```

Simply putting an extra space on the start

```
var inputTextSplit = (" " + inputText).Split(' ')
```

Converting to `List` and using `Insert`, then converting back to an `Array`

```
var inputTextSplit = inputText.Split(' ').ToList();
inputTextSplit.Insert(0,null);
var result = inputTextSplit.ToArray();
```

Allocating a new array, the using `Array.Copy`

```
var inputTextSplit = inputText.Split(' ');
var result = new string[inputTextSplit.Length + 1];
Array.Copy(inputTextSplit, 0, result, 1, inputTextSplit.Length);
```

Resizing the array, and nulling the first element

```
Array.Resize(ref inputTextSplit, inputTextSplit.Length + 1);
Array.Copy(inputTextSplit, 0, inputTextSplit, 1, inputTextSplit.Length - 1);
inputTextSplit[0] = null;
```

using a `Span`.. just for giggles

```
var inputTextSplit = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
var result = new string [inputTextSplit.Length + 1];
inputTextSplit.AsSpan().CopyTo(new Span<string>(result)[1..]);
```

Your own iterator method

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<string> MyOwnFunkySplit(this string source)
   {
      yield return null;
      foreach (var item in source.Split(' '))
         yield return item;
   }
}

...

var inputTextSplit = Console
     .ReadLine()
     .MyOwnFunkySplit()
     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't - split will always put the first segment into *the first* element of the array, which indeed has index 0.

If you really need the first segment to be at index 1 you can:

- alter starting string to always have extra value

  ```
   var inputTextSplit = ("skip " + inputText).Split(' ');
  ```
- if you just need an enumerable where first element does not matter - concat with empty array:

  ```
   var startingAtOne = (new[]{"skip"}).Concat(inputTextSplit);
  ```
- copy array to a new one with an extra element at the beginning -  [Insert a element in String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996229/insert-a-element-in-string-array)

  ```
   var startingAtOne = (new[]{"skip"}).Concat(inputTextSplit).ToArray();
  ```

Note that it is a very strange requirement and probably should be addressed in code that consumes the result.